# Android observer is not updating object in listview

Tags: android, observer-pattern

I am having troubles using `java.util.Observable` in my android application.
In my app, I want to update a `listview` when the data is changed in the background.

So the objects from the `listview` are in the observer. I see them in the `arraylist` from the observer class. In Eclipse Debugging I see the reference to my objects, for example: `at.stockserv.todo.Todo@1a3f2cb7`

One thing I don't understand: When the data is changed in my observer update method

```
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {        
    if (observable instanceof DBObjectUpdateObserver) {         
        ObserverMessage message = (ObserverMessage) data;           
        if (message.getAction() == Actions.messageIdChanged) {
            if (message.getData().get("oldId").equals(Integer.valueOf(getId()))) {
                setId((Integer) message.getData().get("newId"));
                DBObjectUpdateObserver.getInstance().dataHasChanged(this);

            }
        }
    }   

}
```

After setId, suddenly the object has another reference. So in my `listview`, still the old data is stored with the old reference.

My code in the view:

```
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {        
    ObserverMessage message = (ObserverMessage) data;
    if (message.getAction() == Actions.messageDBDataChanged) {          
        if (actNotices.contains(message.getData().get("dbObject"))) {               
            notifyDataSetChanged();             
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data is updated ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
        }           
    }

}
```

`actNotices` ist the `arraylist` with data in the `adapter`. The data is here not changed, but the data should be changed from the first method.

My code of the observer is:

```
public class DBObjectUpdateObserver extends Observable {

 private static DBObjectUpdateObserver instance = new DBObjectUpdateObserver();

 public static DBObjectUpdateObserver getInstance() {
        return instance;
 }

 private DBObjectUpdateObserver() { 

 }

 public void updateId (DBCommunicator dbObject, int oldId, int newId) {
     HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     data.put("oldId", oldId);
     data.put("newId", newId);
     data.put("dbObject", dbObject);
     getInstance().setChanged();
     getInstance().notifyObservers(new ObserverMessage(Actions.messageIdChanged, data));         

 }

 public void dataHasChanged(DBCommunicator dbObject, int oldId, int newId) {
     HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();       
     data.put("dbObject", dbObject);
     data.put("oldId", oldId);
     data.put("newId", newId);
     getInstance().setChanged();
     getInstance().notifyObservers(new ObserverMessage(Actions.messageDBDataChanged, data));         
 }
```

}

What I don't understand is:
The object in the `arraylist` is added to the observer. Some data in the observer object is changed. But the changes are only in the object of the observer, not in the arraylist which I added to the observer. I thought that in the observer there is just a reference to my object in the `arraylist`? So the object in the `arraylist` should change as well when the object in the observer is changed. But this does not work, why?

Can anyone explain me what is happening here?

Comment: Are you using observer pattern for updating data in your list?

Comment: Yes, i am using the observer pattern.

Comment: For that you can update your list data and use notifydatasetchange method which will work exactly as observer. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Comment: The problem is, the data in my adapter is not changed, it is still the same so, notifaydatasetchange is not working

Comment: You don't show your obserable object.  Are you sure you are calling setChanged() before notifyObservers()

Comment: I guess you are saying that you are seeing the update method being called?  can you show your arraylist adapter?

Comment: were is the observer update method, ie what class is implementing update?  It's not clear what the setId method is

Comment: Hi, I added my code of the observer. I have a DBCommunicator class, which calls the updateId method of the observer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now make the whole update process with LocalBroadcasts, now my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Once your data changes call the bellow method.

CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(YourActivity.this, dataSet);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Here your notifying the list adapter that dataSet has been changed.

Comment: I think this should work but I haven't tested it myself

Comment: It will work. If not reply to this will solve the problem